# Can apps take permissions when the Internet is off?

Tags: applications

I would like to know if apps that have permissions like contacts and other files can take this while the Internet is turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App permissions are generally determined at the moment of the installation. If your internet is off, but they have access to certain permissions, they will still have those permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course. The internet being on or off makes no difference. If it didn't work this way, you wouldn't be able to use the camera while in airplane mode, for example.